# jq plot - getting linear x axis ticks

Tags: jqgrid, jqplot

I have a jqPlot chart which is rendered as in the image below.

Iam using LinearAxisRenderer for the x-axis.

But the x-axis values are coming as 0 ,1,1,2,2, etc..

Is there a way to get the values as 0, 1,2,3 etc..

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Code :

```
 $.jqplot(ctrlId, [graphPt], {
        title: chartTitle,
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15, formatString: '%s' },
            shadow: false,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal',
                barMargin: 2
            }
        },
        axesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer,
            min: 0,      // minimum numerical value of the axis.  Determined automatically.
            pad: 1.3,       // a factor multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the
            // axis range so that data points don't fall on the edges of the axis.

            tickOptions: {
                mark: 'outside',    // Where to put the tick mark on the axis 'outside', 'inside' or 'cross',
                markSize: 95,                  // 
                showGridline: false, // wether to draw a gridline (across the whole grid) at this tick,
                show: true,         // wether to show the tick (mark and label),
                showLabel: true,    // wether to show the text label at the tick,
                formatString: '%d'   // format string to use with the axis tick formatter
            },
            showTicks: true,        // wether or not to show the tick labels,
            showTickMarks: true    // wether or not to show the tick marks
        },

        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            },
            xaxis: {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    mark: 'cross', 
                    markSize: 2
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `tickinterval` property to your `xaxis` settings.

```
xaxis: {
             renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                mark: 'cross', 
                markSize: 2,   
            },
            tickInterval: 1 //ADD THIS
        }
```

From the [jqplot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.tickInterval):

**tickInterval** - number of units between ticks.  Mutually exclusive with numberTicks.

Answer (score 0):

Don'forget to add 'max' and 'min' properties. If your are manipulating xaxis ticks individually. I've Lost lots of time on that.

```
xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                mark: 'cross', 
                markSize: 2,   
            },
            tickInterval: 1 
            max :0,
            min :100
        }
```