# jqPlot horizontal bar chart with tick label at top of bar

Tags: jqplot

I have a jqPlot hor. barchart like this one. [jq plot - getting linear x axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765521/jq-plot-getting-linear-x-axis-ticks)

I want to be able to put y-axis tick labels (like software and services, israel in the pic)
on top of respective bars using some parameters or renderer instead of fiddling with css.

Is there an easy way to do that? Thanks in advance.

so far, my code looks like below.

`
function drawChart() {

```
    var data = new Array(3);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = new Array(2);
        data[i][0] = Math.random() * 100;
        data[i][1] = 'text-' + (i + 1);
    }

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('votingresult', [
            data,
            ], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
                    shadow: false,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barDirection: 'horizontal',
                        barPadding: 20,
                        barMargin: 0,
                        barWidth: 20,
                        varyBarColor: true,                            
                    }
                },
                gridPadding: { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
                grid: {
                    drawGridLines: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    shadow: false
                },
                axesDefaults: {                        
                    showTicks: false,
                    shadow: false                        
                },
                axes: {
                    yaxis: {
                            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,                                 
                            tickOptions: {                                    
                                fontSize: '10pt',                                    
                                mark: 'inside',
                                showLabel: false
                            }                                
                    }
                }
            });
}`
```

I want jqplot like one shown in the right side in this flickr picture.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/surajshrestha/7455033636/sizes/l/in/photostream/

Jeroen: I have looked into point labels. But, here, I am talking about axis label to be inside the graph.

Comment: What have you tried? How does your code look now? Have you looked at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php or http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html#$.jqplot.PointLabels

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and ended up just writing a function to append content to the graph DIV rather than try and fiddle with JQPlot. You just have to adjust the barMargin option to account for the spacing.

```
        function makeSectionLabels(jsonObject, domObject, topPadding, spacing) {
            var html = "<div class='bar-chart-sections' style='padding-top:"+topPadding+"'>";
            $.each(jsonObject, function(index, value){
                html += "<h5 style='margin-bottom:"+spacing+"'>"+value+"</h5>"
            });
                html += "</div>"
            $(domObject).append(html);
        };
```